# How do I Label colorbar ticks in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to manually set my `colorbar's` tick labels and its position horizontal. For example:

```
 Min=0.8;       
 Max=12;    
 h = colorbar('horiz');       
 set(h,'location','southoutside')
 set(h,'XTickLabel',{num2str(Min),'mm'  ,num2str(Max)})
```

However, the above code repeats the tick labels label. How can I set number of  tick  manually?
I want my `colorbar` to appear something like the following:

```
****----------------****         //colorbar
min        [mm]           max
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the locations of your ticks like so:

```
set(h, 'XTick', [Min, (Min+Max)/2, Max])
```

Be aware that this will probably not look correct, unless the colour limits of your plot are set to the range [0.8, 12]. You can do this with:

```
set(gca, 'CLim', [Min, Max])
```

Furthermore, a better way of adding the units 'mm' to your colourbar would be as follows:

```
h = colorbar('horiz');  
set(gca, 'CLim', [Min, Max])
set(h, 'XTick', [Min, Max])
set(h,'XTickLabel',{num2str(Min) ,num2str(Max)}) %# don't add units here...
xlabel(h, 'mm')                                  %# ...use xlabel to add units
```